# Tkinter - Open one window and close another

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have a login screen and when the login is successful, the screen is closed and a new screen is created. The problem is , when I do just like the following code , both screens opens at the same time. If you have any suggestions to improve the code , please do! :)

```
from Tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
import tkMessageBox

class Tela_login(Frame):
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1024x768")
    root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    background_image = PhotoImage(file="fundo.gif")
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        fundo = Label(image=self.background_image)
        fundo.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)
        self.create_screen()

    def create_screen(self):
        self.label1 = Label(text="Login",font = ("Arial",60))
        self.label2 = Label(text="Senha",font = ("Arial",60))
        self.login = Entry(font = ("Arial",60),width = 10)
        self.senha = Entry(show="*",font = ("Arial",60), width= 10)
        self.entrar = Button(text="Entrar",command=lambda : self.efetua_login(),font = ("Arial",60),width=10)

        self.label1.grid(padx=258,pady=(70,0))
        self.login.grid(padx=258)
        self.label2.grid(padx=258,pady=(50,0))
        self.senha.grid(padx=258)
        self.entrar.grid(padx=258,pady=(50,0))

    def efetua_login(self):
        login = self.login.get()
        senha = self.senha.get()

        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='123qwe', host='192.168.56.1', database='teste')
        cursor = cnx
        cursor = cnx.cursor()

        query = ("SELECT nome, senha FROM funcionario WHERE nome = %s AND senha = %s")
        cursor.execute(query, (login,senha))
        row = cursor.fetchone()

        if row is None:

            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Erro","Usuario ou Senha Incorretos")

        else:
            app2 = Tela_principal()
            self.root.destroy()
            Tela_principal.root.mainloop()


class Tela_principal(Frame):
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry = ("1024x768")
    root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

    def inicia(self, master):
        background_image = PhotoImage(file="fundo.gif")
        app2 = Tela_principal(self.root)
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

app = Tela_login(Tela_login.root)
Tela_login.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to have two `Tk()` instances running. For the login screen there's two routes you could go. You could withdraw the root window and make the login screen a `Toplevel` withdrawing the root window upon the Toplevel's initialization window and once the login is successful destroy the toplevel and raise the root window. Or, even easier you could put your login screen in a separate frame, hide the main frame using `pack_forget` or `grid_forget` depending on your layout and then login / destroy or hide the frame and recall `pack` or `grid` to show the main app frame again.

Answer (score 0):

Slayer , I did like you said and it worked like a charm!
Here is the example code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Tela_login(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.button1 = Button(text = "Open",command = lambda: self.open_login())
        self.button1.grid()

    def open_login(self):
        root2 = Toplevel()
        app2 = Tela_principal(root2)

class Tela_principal(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Tela_login(root)
root.mainloop()
```